# can't set src to iframe from javascript function

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have the  html structure like this

```
<form id="form_search">
    <input type="text" id="url_iframe"/>
    <button id="search">Start</button>
</form>
<iframe id="iframe_search" >
</iframe>
```

and I trying to set the iframe scr from javascript like this

```
window.onload = function ()
{
   document.getElementById('search').onclick = inicializar;

   function inicializar ()
   {
     var url_iframe = "http://localhost/site/index.php";
     document.getElementById('iframe_search').src = url_iframe;            
   }
}
```

But the problem is that the iframe not retain the scr value...

How can I set property to iframe?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to prevent the default event behavior on your mouse click event. A better option would be to add the event to the submit event to support older browsers.

http://jsfiddle.net/xd2d9/1/

```
event.preventDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should move your `inicializar()` function outside the `window.onload()` function because I guess you will need a function with a global scope to run it `onclick`.